# Customizing AccountId

Tags: accountid, config, traits

In my runtime I'm using `pub type AccountId = <<Signature as Verify>::Signer as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;`. Within my pallet I also need this type to implement `From<SomeType>`. I attempted to add `type CustomAccountId: From<SomeType>;` to my pallet's config, but encountered numerous errors. I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track. What is the proper way to achieve this?

**Edit**: To be more specific, I have the following type definition in my pallet, which is also used in a StorageMap

```rust
type AccountId: IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::AccountId> + From<H160>;

// some code...

#[pallet::storage]
pub(super) type AssetOwner<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, U256, <T as pallet::Config>::AccountId, OptionQuery>;
```

Some errors I got:

```
error[E0599]: the function or associated item `get` exists for struct `StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageAssetOwner<T>, Blake2_128Concat, U256, <T as Config>::AccountId>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
...
error[E0277]: the trait bound `<T as pallet::Config>::AccountId: std::clone::Clone` is not satisfied
...
the trait bound `<T as pallet::Config>::AccountId: WrapperTypeEncode` is not satisfied
...
error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `&<T as pallet::Config>::AccountId`
...
```

These errors make me suspect that I'm not extending the AccountId type from the runtime config correctly. What is the proper way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Could you include what you need it for and provide the errors that you have encountered?

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas I would like to "extend" the AccountId type used within the pallet so that it also has to implement `From<H160>` and `Into<H160>`, enabling conversion between the `T::AccountId` type and `H160`.

Comment: Can you paste the error and share the implementation? will be easy if we can replicate your issue

Comment: Could you give a link to your repo?

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas sure: https://github.com/freeverseio/laos-ownership-node/blob/refactor/add_from_impl_to_account_id/pallets/living-assets-ownership/src/lib.rs#L55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Outdated
>
> The error message is still unclear. It appears that the error
> originated from the runtime instead of the pallet. When passing
> `AccountId = YourImplementation`, `YourImplementation` must meet all
> trait bounds.
>
> You can check how other projects implement their account id here:
> [link](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/8b0ff04104d4d5c2354c8eef4f7de0dffc27dff6/primitives/account/src/lib.rs#L32).
>
> ---
>
> For example, this line `#[derive(Clone)]` at [line
> 30](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/8b0ff04104d4d5c2354c8eef4f7de0dffc27dff6/primitives/account/src/lib.rs#L30)
> will satisfy the following error: ``` error[E0277]: the trait bound
> `<T as pallet::Config>::AccountId: std::clone::Clone` is not satisfied
>
> ```
> I believe so.
> ```

---

After reviewing your source code, it appears that the `IsType` function removes the trait bound of `frame_system::Config::AccountId`. It seems there is no straightforward way to extend the associated type for this.

If you really want to do this that way, try:

```rs
type AccountId: IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::AccountId> + From<H160> + Parameter + Member + MaxEncodedLen;
```

This almost re-define a new `AccountId`.

Check: https://github.com/freeverseio/laos-ownership-node/pull/143.

---

There is another way, use the `frame_system::Config::AccountId` directly and provide a converter for it. For example:

```rs
trait Config: frame_system::Config {
    type H160ToAccountId: Convert<Self::AccountId, H160>
}

trait Convert<A, B> {
    fn convert(a: A) -> B;
}

enum H160ToAccountIdConverter {}
impl Convert<AccountId, H160> for H160ToAccountIdConverter {
    ...
}

impl your_pallet::Config for Runtime {
    type H160ToAccountId = H160ToAccountIdConverter;
}
```

Comment: I'm currently working within the pallet directory to test its functionality. Despite adding `#[derive(Clone, Decode, Encode, TypeInfo, Debug, Eq, PartialEq, MaxEncodedLen, Ord, PartialOrd, derive_more::Display, Serialize, Deserialize)]` to my test AccountId struct, I'm still getting the errors stated above

Comment: Updated my answer.